# how can I include a loginSuccessHandler and loginFailureHandler while keeping the jwt Authentication provider

Tags: authentication, security, jwt

I implemented a JWT Authentication process and it works fine, then when adding a feature to limit login attempts through a **CustomAuthenticationFailure**  **CustomAuthenticationSuccess** handlers and adding them through the ***.formLogin*** configuration the authentication process fails indicating that the credentials are wrong even though they are correct (meaning it detects the email in the database but not the passsword). When I did a research I figured that the JWT-based authentication and form-based authentication are interfering each other in same endpoint. How can I keep the jwt authentication provider while also keeping the features provided by the **CustomAuthenticationFailure** and **CustomAuthenticationSuccess**
Here's the SecurityFilterChain

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers("/api/v1/auth/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/user/password_recovery").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/user/process_password_recovery").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .sessionManagement(sessionManagement -> sessionManagement
                        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                )
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
        http
                .formLogin(login -> login
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/api/v1/auth/authenticate") //Customize the login page
                    .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler)
                    .permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Autowired
    private CustomLoginFailureHandler loginFailureHandler;
    @Autowired
    private CustomLoginSuccessHandler loginSuccessHandler;
```

and here's the CustomLoginFailureHandler class:

```
@Component
public class CustomLoginFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    User user;
    @Autowired
    UserServices userServices;
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            AuthenticationException exception)
                throws IOException, ServletException {

        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        Optional<User> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmail(email);
        if (userOptional.isPresent()) {
            User user = userOptional.get();
            if (user.isAccNonLocked()) {
                if (user.getFailedAttempt() < UserServices.MAX_FAILED_ATTEMPTS - 1) {
                    userServices.increaseFailedAttempt(user);
                }
                else {
                    userServices.lock(user);
                    String errorMessage = "Your account has been locked due to 3 failed attempts."
                            + "\nIt will be unlocked after 24 hours.";
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.LOCKED.value());
                    response.getWriter().write("{\"error\": \"" + errorMessage + "\"}");
                    return;
                }
            }
            else if (!user.isAccNonLocked()) {
                boolean test = userServices.unlock(user);
                if (test) {
                    String Message = "Your account has been unlocked."
                            + "\nPlease try to login again.";
                    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.LOCKED.value());
                    response.getWriter().write("{\"error\": \"" + Message + "\"}");
                    return;
                }
            }
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value());
            response.getWriter().write("{\"error\": \"Invalid credentials\"}");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Email not exist");
            //throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Impossible de trouver l'utilisateur avec l'e-mail: " + email);
            response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
            response.getWriter().write("{\"error\": \"Email not found\"}");
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't manage the limit like this. Since the handler doesn't own the context (what if you have multiple servers running and validating - each request can go to a different handler)
You need to add a DB and store the login counts, just remember to revoke them or it will get filled